# Is it possible to add names and description for validation rules in laravel request class

Tags: php, laravel

I have request class :

```
class UpdateProductRequest extends ApiRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

But I want something similar to :

```
class UpdateProductRequest extends ApiRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=> [
                'name' => 'Product name',
                'description' => 'Product name description',
                'validation' => 'required',
                'type' => 'string',
            ],
            'description'=> [
                'name' => 'Product description',
                'description' => 'Product description description',
                'validation' => 'required',
                'type' => 'string',
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Because I want use this additional data for Rest API documentation. I don't want to duplicate names like this one:

```
class UpdateProductRequest extends ApiRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function apiData(){
        return [
            'name'=> [
                'name' => 'Product name',
                'description' => 'Product name description',
                'type' => 'string',
            ],
            'description'=> [
                'name' => 'Product description',
                'description' => 'Product description description',
                'type' => 'string',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `rules` to use your `apiData` like folowing:

```
class UpdateProductRequest extends ApiRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function apiData()
    {
        return [
            'name'=> [
                'name' => 'Product name',
                'description' => 'Product name description',
                'validation' => 'required',
                'type' => 'string',
            ],
            'description'=> [
                'name' => 'Product description',
                'description' => 'Product description description',
                'validation' => 'required',
                'type' => 'string',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return array_map(function($item){
            return $item['validation'];
        }, $this->apiData());
    }
}
```

But it might be a good idea to look at [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) for documentation. There are few bindings for larave: https://packagist.org/search/?q=swagger%20laravel

**EDIT:**

`rules` is a kind of adapter for `apiData`, which holds the data. So for the never-mentioned-question you need to put your logic in `apiData` without changing logic in `rules`:

```
public function apiData()
{
    return array_diff_key(
        (new Requests\Backend\UpdateProductRequest)->apiData(),
        ['something' => false]
    );
}

public function rules()
{
    return array_map(function($item){
        return $item['validation'];
    }, $this->apiData());
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did but I have Backend/UpdateProductRequest and Api\UpdateProductRequest now is not straightforward to copy rules from backend request to api request...

Comment: Sounds quite bad, but I am not quite following. Why would you copy rules between classes and how it is related to the question you asked?

Comment: public function rules()
    {
        $rules = (new Requests\Backend\UpdateProductRequest)->rules();
        unset($rules['something']);
        return $rules;
    }

Comment: Ok you helped me quite, I was just looking for some ideas how to achieve this. Your last solution is not perfect because then I need to edit all current backend request and I don't want apiData() function in backend requests...